# BIRT Report: How to add table borders in Data Cube

Tags: report, birt, data-cube

I have a report with the output as follows:

```
no       Date       Patid  Patient Name       Doctor Name           Medicine          Qty

1.    2 Feb 2023     100       Patient A         Doc AB                Adol           30
                                                                   Panadol            10
                                                                   Paracetamol        10
```

I was able to achieve this output in the form of data cube. But this table has no borders. How to add borders for this table in BIRT Report. Please specify the steps

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the BIRT Report Designer, and Drag&Drop the data cube into your page, it uses the "cross tab"-element. You can set the outside border of the cross tab directly on the "cross tab" element under "property border". The internal borders can be set on the "cell" sub-elements.

[image]

Comment: Ok. thank u. Could u please help me with another case. Its related. I have implemented the logic which u proposed. but I have anothere issue. Please help. Please follow the below link

Link:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75589169/birt-report-i-have-performed-data-cube-operation-but-want-to-group-medicine-wi)